# jQuery Accordion ui - show/hide another div when panel is active

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using the jQuery ui accordion.
I have a quote in a div I would like to display with each accordion panel when they're active. I can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas? I was trying something like this...

`if ($("#section1").hasClass("ui-accordion-content-active")) {
            $("#quote1").show();}`

```
<div id="quote1"><em>quote1</em></p></div>
<div id="accordion">
 <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div id="section1" class="sec1">
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscitait eget.
    </p>
```

I got a little closer, but still need some help. I've changed the html to the following:

```
<div class="subcontent" id="123"><em>quote1</em></p></div>
<div class="subcontent" id="124"><em>quote2</em></p></div>


<div id="accordion">
<h3>Section 1</h3>

 <div data-id="123" class="topic">
 <p>
 Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. 
 ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum 
 amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra 
 </p>
 </div>
 <h3 id="section2">Section 2</h3>
 <div data-id="124" class="topic">
 <p>
 Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit 
 purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis 
</p>
</div></div>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
 $( function() {

$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true, });

$("div").click(function(){
        if($(".topic").hasClass("ui-accordion-content-active") ==  
true) {
     // hide open subcontents
    $('.subcontent:visible').hide();
      $('.mainquote:visible').hide();
    // fade in new selected subcontent
     $('.subcontent[id='+$(this).attr('data-    
id')+']').delay(500).fadeIn();    
         } else {
              $('.subcontent:visible').hide(); } 



});});
```

Without the "click" function, this doesn't work. Anyway for the quote to appear without the "click" function?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do, I do not know if it's very clean

html

```js
 $( function() {

$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true, });

$("h3").click(function(){
        if($(".topic").hasClass("ui-accordion-content-active") == true) {
         $('.subcontent:visible').hide();
      $('.mainquote:visible').hide();
    console.log($(this).data("id"));  
    $('.subcontent[id='+$(this).data("id")+']').delay(500).fadeIn(); 
 } else {
              $('.subcontent:visible').hide(); }

})
;});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="subcontent" id="123"><em>quote1</em></div>
<div class="subcontent" id="124"><em>quote2</em></div>


<div id="accordion">
<h3 data-id="123">Section 1</h3>

 <div   class="topic">
 <p>
 Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. 
 ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum 
 amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra 
 </p>
 </div>
 <h3 data-id="124"id="section2">Section 2</h3>
 <div  class="topic">
 <p>
 Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit 
 purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis 
</p>
</div></div>
```